# Retrieve result from sqlite Foxit SDK FullTextSearch

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, foxit, foxit-reader

I'm trying FullTextSearch functions from Foxit Pdf Sdk in Xamarin.Android.
According to their document, result is kept in sqlite.
I have a problem with retrieving result from sqlite and there is no document about retrieving in Foxit Sdk.

Here is my code.

```
int errCode = Library.Initialize(sn, key);
            if (errCode != Constants.EErrSuccess)
                return string.Empty;

            var search = new FullTextSearch();
            string dbPath = database;
            search.SetDataBasePath(dbPath);
            // Get document source information.
            DocumentsSource source = new DocumentsSource(directory);

            // Create a Pause callback object implemented by users to pause the updating process.
            PauseUtil pause = new PauseUtil(30);

            // Start to update the index of PDF files which receive from the source.
            Progressive progressive = search.StartUpdateIndex(source, pause, false);
            int state = Progressive.EToBeContinued;
            while (state == Progressive.EToBeContinued)
            {
                state = progressive.Resume();
            }

            // Create a callback object which will be invoked when a matched one is found.
            MySearchCallback searchCallback = new MySearchCallback();

            // Search the specified keyword from the indexed data source.
            bool isFinished = search.SearchOf(searchIndex, FullTextSearch.ERankHitCountASC, searchCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

First I created a property in SearchCallBack funtion.

```
public List<DtoSearchResult> SearchResults { get; set; }
```

When override RetrieveSearchResult is processing, I added result into list

```
public override int RetrieveSearchResult(string filePath, int pageIndex, string matchResult, int matchStartTextIndex, int matchEndTextIndex)
        {
            try
            {
                DtoSearchResult result = new DtoSearchResult();
                result.FilePath = filePath;
                result.MatchResult = matchResult;
                result.PageIndex = pageIndex;
                SearchResults.Add(result);
                return 0;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            
        }
```

And then I called SearchResults property from activity.

```
searchCallback.SearchResults = new List<DataTransferObjects.DtoSearchResult>();
bool isFinished = search.SearchOf(searchIndex, FullTextSearch.ERankHitCountASC, 
searchCallback);
var result = searchCallback.SearchResults;
```